What are Koro-Sensei’s weaknesses?
Occasionally throughout the show, a bulletin will appear on the screen whenever a new weakness of Kori-Sensei is discovered.
However, the show shows all of them written in Japanese, because it’s a Japanese show.
So what are the weaknesses in English?

this is his wiki page, listing information, plot, and weaknesses in order in english
https://ansatsukyoshitsu.fandom.com/wiki/Korosensei

koro sensei weakness is being submerged in water,easily get distracted by beautiful woman, anti sensei weapon,special rubber knives and bb pellets designed to work against his body

Welcome to Anime.SE! Are these the weaknesses shown on the bulletins that the OP is referring to? Can you provide references for each of these?

These could very well be some of them, but there are some ~35 weaknesses shown throughout the show, and these definitely aren’t all of them.
